# React Native: Dispatching action to fetch data before rendering (Redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm developing a react native app with redux as a state management and trying the following implementation:

- Fetching data from Server (Firebase) before rendering the app. I have a loading screen, which is working fine, but i cant dispatch my function in it for fetching the data from server and write directly to the current state. I dont see that the state is changed, but when I saving the code (as it is) again the state is updated as I expected. So i think my code is fetching the data after the first rendering is done.

I cant figure out the the problem. Cause i put my code for dispatching in the "useeffect" hook as i should or not?

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, View} from 'react-native';
import {Images, useTheme} from '@config';
import {Image, Text} from '@components';
import styles from './styles';
import {ApplicationActions} from '@actions';
import { store } from '/Users/user1/KitaList/app/store/index.js'


export default function Loading({navigation}) {
  const {colors} = useTheme();

  const onProcess = () => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      navigation.replace('Main');
    }, 2500);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   store.dispatch(ApplicationActions.ongetKitadata()); //Executing dispatchting getting data 
    onProcess();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Image source={Images.logo} style={styles.logo} resizeMode="contain" />
        <Text title1 style={{marginTop: 10}}>
          MyApp
        </Text>
        <Text headline primaryColor style={{marginTop: 10}}>
          MyApp DIRECTORY
        </Text>
      </View>
      <ActivityIndicator
        size="large"
        color={colors.text}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 260,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you don't want your App render before the data are ready, you can put the loader img and stuff in the main app-root div, wait for page load, fetch data with fetch API for example, then initialise your store and render the app as usual.

Comment: Also, your dispach is async, so your render is called before the response is returned. You can also use async and await to make your async call like a sync one.